# simplify expression with dot, get correct number of dimensions

Tags: python, sympy

I would like to create a sympy expression with `dot` product of a constant that translates into `numpy.dot` upon `lambdify` and on which I can do `simplify`.

Using a `sympy.Matrix` unfortunately always adds an extra dimension such that the shape of a `dot()` always has a `1` at the end:

```
import numpy
import sympy


class dot(sympy.Function):
    pass


a = sympy.Matrix([1, 2, 3])
beta = sympy.Symbol('beta')
x = sympy.Symbol('x')

expr = beta * dot(x, a)
expr = sympy.simplify(expr)
f = sympy.lambdify((x, beta), expr)

x = numpy.random.rand(7, 77, 3)
beta = numpy.random.rand(7, 77)
f(x, beta)
```

This gives the error

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (7,77) (7,77,1)
```

Replacing the `sympy.Matrix` by an equivalent `numpy.array` makes the `dot` work just right, but fails at `simplify` (with Python 3). ([Bug filed.](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/12665))

I'm running out of ideas of how to work around the issue. Any hints?

Comment: Why don't you throw away the extra dimension conditionally: `fx = f(x); if len(fx.shape)==3 and fx.shape[2]==1: fx = fx[0]`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, the expression in the actual code is more complex in that the output of `dot` is multiplied with another vector. Evaluating `f(x)` then gives the errors like `operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,4,1190) (3,4,1190,1)`. I will adapt the question accordingly.

Comment: You may want to look at the N-dimensional array in SymPy: http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/tensor/array.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [this bug](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/12665) is fixed in master (see the [PR](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/12670)), the following now works

```
import numpy
import sympy


class dot(sympy.Function):
    pass


a = numpy.array([1, 2, 3])
beta = sympy.Symbol('beta')
x = sympy.Symbol('x')

expr = beta * dot(x, a)
expr = sympy.simplify(expr)
f = sympy.lambdify((x, beta), expr)

x = numpy.random.rand(7, 77, 3)
beta = numpy.random.rand(7, 77)
f(x, beta)
```